# Spring Cloud Compatibility with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-cloud-stream

Currently the Spring Cloud documentation contains a [matrix](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud) describing binary compatibility between Spring Cloud and Spring Boot. However, as Spring Boot has now jumped to 2.7.x, the matrix remains unchanged. Is there any information on how the two tracks reconcile going forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That information is indeed out of date. It will eventually be updated to point to https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Supported-Versions#supported-releases